# How can you tokenize a bash string into an array when the string includes a * character?

Tags: bash

I have long used code similar to :

```
string="abc 123 xyz"
fields=( ${string} )
echo "The 3rd field = ${fields[2]}"
```

to break a string into fields and reference a particular element within the string.

But I ran into a strange use case today where the source string contained an '*' asterisks character. ie:

```
string="abc * xyz"
fields=( ${string} )
echo "The 3rd field = ${fields[2]}"
declare -p fields
```

In this case, the '*' does not map into the array literally, rather it appears to get expanded to a list of environment variables, and the array ends up with a much larger list or values that do not represent the original string.

Three questions:

1. What exactly is * being expanded to?
2. Can this expansion be disabled so the code will behave in the intended fashion?
3. Is there a better way to accomplish the transformation of a string into an array of tokens that do not suffer from this side effect?

Answer (score 2):

Let `read` do it; unquoted parameter expansions are subject to pathname expansion as well as word splitting, so `*` is expanded to all file names in the current working directory.

```
read -a fields <<< "$string"
```

Alternatively, pathname expansion can also be disabled, allowing

```
set -f
fields=( $string )
set +f
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the info I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

1. - is expanded to all the files in current dir, same as `ls *`
2. Use single quote. {string="abc '*' xyz"}
3. Maybe, but this is the good way :-)